# what is the correct date function to count the number of occurrences per weekly basis

Tags: sql-server

I would like to calculate the number of records available per daily basis and consolidate report on weekly basis. I have written below sql but it is displaying the data more than a week.

```
select convert(varchar, CreatedDateTime, 101), COUNT(CreatedDateTime) as Count 
from dbo.table 
group by convert(varchar, CreatedDateTime, 101)

Union all

select 'Grand Total' CreatedDateTime,COUNT(CreatedDateTime) 
from dbo.table 
where CreatedDateTime >= DATEADD(WEEK,-1,getdate());
```

Please suggest .

Comment: Delete this question.  Ask another question with sample data, desired results, and your sample query.

Answer (score 1):

you were missing a where on you converted date ,TRY:

```
select convert(varchar, CreatedDateTime, 101), COUNT(CreatedDateTime) as Count 
FROM [Test_DB].[dbo].[table]
where convert(varchar, CreatedDateTime, 101) >= DATEADD(WEEK,-1,getdate())
group by convert(varchar, CreatedDateTime, 101)
Union all
select 'Grand Total' ,COUNT(CreatedDateTime) 
FROM [Test_DB].[dbo].[table]
where CreatedDateTime >= DATEADD(WEEK,-1,getdate());
```

Comment: this is the warning i have got "Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.
"

Comment: Moreover i am looking to add column name "GrandTotal" which would display the count of all the rows .  please suggest.

Comment: see now, i improved my answer, you were missing a where on your first dateset

Comment: @ user3680496,  Thanks a lot for your help. this solved my problems. Again thanks everyone for their continuous support and guidance on this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I created some sample data to use

```
CREATE TABLE CreatedDateTime
(
CreatedDateTime DATETIME
)
```

Inserted the data into the table above

```
INSERT INTO CreatedDateTime 
    VALUES
    (GETDATE()-8),
    (GETDATE()-8),
    (GETDATE()-8),
    (GETDATE()-8),
    (GETDATE()-8),
    (GETDATE()-8),
    (GETDATE()-8),
    (GETDATE()-6),
    (GETDATE()-6),
    (GETDATE()-1),
    (GETDATE()-1),
    (GETDATE()-1),
    (GETDATE()-1),
    (GETDATE()-1),
    (GETDATE()-1),
    (GETDATE()-2),
    (GETDATE()-2),
    (GETDATE()-2),
    (GETDATE()-2),
    (GETDATE()-2)
```

The query

```
select     
convert(varchar, CreatedDateTime, 101) as Date, 
COUNT(CreatedDateTime) as Total     
from dbo.CreatedDateTime     
where CreatedDateTime >= DATEADD(Week,-1,getdate())    
GROUP BY ROLLUP(CreatedDateTime)
```

Comment: @ iamrichhowell , thanks a lot for your quick response. Now am able to see the below output. is it possible to show the output  of one particular day in one row instead of individual counts .
Current output:
04/17/2017 1
04/17/2017 1
04/17/2017 1
04/17/2017 1
04/17/2017 1
NULL 5

Comment: @suresh what version of SQL are you using? I get each day as a separate row with a total at the bottom of all rows for that week.